# Conway sequence in swift

Tags: swift, swift5, swift4.2

Can anyone help me out with this sequece.
I have tried multiple times but not getting solution. Some of the solution looks like as follows

```
1
11
21
1211
11121
```

But i need following solution. I want to print this sequece in console.

```
1 
11 
21 
1211 
3112 
132112 
311322
```

Comment: And what’s the programming part of the question?

Comment: Want to make code which print the pattern like i mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var last = [1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2]
var next = [Int]()

func getNext() {
    if last.count == 0 { return }
    let first = last.first!
    let firstCount = last.filter{ $0 == first }.count
    next.append(firstCount)
    next.append(first)
    last.removeAll { $0 == first }
    getNext()
}

getNext()
print(next)//[3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2]
```